# how to do <a href/> properly with thymeleaf?

Tags: java, html, thymeleaf

I am struggling with my thymeleaf template, as follows.

So, I have an *Arraylist* of urls of the same name, which I want to display on a page.

```
<a th:each="u:${urls}" th:href="${u}" th:value="${u}">[[${u}]]<br></a>
```

The problem is that, when I click on one of the rendered links. It simply appends my url to the current url. e.g.:

`http://localhost:8080/www.google.com`

What's going on here? and how should I achieve what I'm attempting to? I have tried "base href", to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The urls need to have `http://` or `https://` in front of them.  (If they don't they are considered relative urls and the browser correctly appends `http://localhost:8080/` to them.)  You can add them in like this if you want:

```
<a th:each="u: ${urls}" th:href="|https://${u}|" th:text="${u}" />
```